# NHibernate - outer join, not lazy, ignoring not found - how do you build the objects in one statement?

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, orm, fluent

I've read many posts about this, the last being a statement saying the behaviour i'm experiencing the the expected if not preferred way.

I've got a handful of domain models mapped to their database tables.

I'm using a Criteria object to query them.

```
 var query = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Posting))
                .CreateAlias("Person", "person", JoinType.InnerJoin).SetFetchMode("Person", FetchMode.Eager)
                .CreateAlias("Location", "location", JoinType.InnerJoin).SetFetchMode("Location", FetchMode.Eager)
                .CreateAlias("Post", "post", JoinType.InnerJoin).SetFetchMode("Post", FetchMode.Eager)
                .CreateAlias("post.Zone", "postzone", JoinType.LeftOuterJoin).SetFetchMode("post.Zone", FetchMode.Select)
```

It produces the exact statment I'm looking for.  I'd expect it to populate the objects eagerly (which it does) and leave nulls for post.Zone where the relationship fails.

In my mapping i've had to say not-found=ignore (Notfound.Ignore() FNH) which due to the outer join is causing NH to generate a number of sub-query - all on the Zone table - which doesn't seem necessary to me, especially as it already had the data it need to populate the Zone object.

Can anyone she any light on any changes I can make to the Mapping or Query/Criteria to keep this load to a single query, or should I expect an extra statement for every record outer joined to?

Thanks,
Sam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is unfortunatly a known issue that `not-found=ignore` causes additional selects. There have been bug reports filed for this in both [NHibernate](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-1001) and [Hibernate](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-3025) for quite some time (2007) and currently no known work around has been made available other than removing `not-found=ignore` or changing the data present in the database so it is no longer required.

A possible work around, although not a nice one, would be to have a stored procedure perform the query you want and then call this from NHibernate. This would remove the redundant queries.

Comment: Really?  So there's actually no way to populate an outer joined entity from the initial query that actually holds the data it needs.  The root data transformer (can't remember type name) does a good job or normalising the object structure, but I just can understand why the outer joined records couldn't be build? Is there not another fetch strategy that loads the at once?

Comment: @sambomartin Unfortunatly not as far as I know - we suffer from the exact same issue in some of our legacy tables and have so far been unable in finding any good work around for this issue. The last reply in the NHibernate bug report says it all really unfortunatly.